# Finding percentage value of standard deviation when given number of elements in sample, and population's standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

I'm faced with an exercise that goes as such:

> "A sample of 81 elements is taken from a population whose standard
> deviation is 3.
>
> What is the approximate value of the mean's sample deviation, in
> percentage?"

I can then pick from a list of choices:

- 54%
- 12%
- 67%
- 20%
- 33%

I know for a fact that the right answer is 33%, but I can't figure out why.

When hearing about "standard deviation in percentage" I instantly think of multiplying the standard deviation's value by 100 and dividing that by the mean/average, the problem being I'm not given the mean. How do I go about this?

Comment: The standard error of the mean is SEM$=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}=\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$ (central limit theorem).

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. On multiple textbooks I kept seeing $ \frac{\sigma}{N} $ which was giving me the wrong value.